# Array Filter devuelve Array vacio

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic

Tengo el siguiente Array de objetos y necesito meterlo en una función que me retorne el mismo array pero  solo con los objetos que tengan el código 11111-1 y 22222-2. Lo estoy tratando de hacer con la siguiente función pero al ejecutarlo me retorna un array vacío. También intente con foreach pero me daba otro error.
Posteriormente tomare este array y lo recorreré con un ngfor para crear cards.

```js
filtraRow(rows) {
  return rows.filter(linea => linea.Codigo === '11111-1' || linea.Codigo === '22222-2')
 }
```

```
    [
      {

        BRUTO: 66990
        CANTIDAD: 1
        CANTRMA: 0
        CODIGO: "12345-6"
        DESCRIPCION: "CAMA"
        IDE_B2B_DESPACHO: 11111
        ITEM: "12345-6"
        LINEA: 1
        LISTA: 119990
        PEDIDO: 22222
        SUCURSAL: 555
        VALOR: 56294
        },
    {
        BRUTO: 14990
        CANTIDAD: 1
        CANTRMA: 0
        CODIGO: "11111-1"
        DESCRIPCION: "Flete"
        IDE_B2B_DESPACHO: 11111
        ITEM: "9999"
        LINEA: 2
        LISTA: 0
        PEDIDO: 22222
        SUCURSAL: 555
        VALOR: 12597
    },
   {
        BRUTO: 14990
        CANTIDAD: 1
        CANTRMA: 0
        CODIGO: "22222-2"
        DESCRIPCION: "Armado"
        IDE_B2B_DESPACHO: 11111
        ITEM: "8888"
        LINEA: 2
        LISTA: 0
        PEDIDO: 22222
        SUCURSAL: 555
        VALOR: 12597
    },
    ]
```

Comment: ¿Probaste `linea.CODIGO` (en mayúsculas)?... Además, ¿podrías poner el código completo? El array que escribiste tiene errores de sintaxis. Siempre conviene incluir un [mcve]

Comment: como dice @Pollo , ademas tu codigo funciona bien sacando esos errores por ej todas las propiedades separadas o la declaracion de la function , y las propiedades son sensibles a mayuscula y minuscula obj.codigo  ≠ obj.CODIGO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como en una respuesta de arriba te indican las propiedades son sensibles a las mayúsculas

```
filtraRow(rows) {
  return rows.filter(linea => linea.CODIGO === '11111-1' || linea.CODIGO === '22222-2');
}
```

Mi recomendación es que evites tener dichas propiedades en mayúscula sostenida y utilices [Camel case](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)

Comment: El problema no es el uso de mayúsculas sostenidas; el problema es la inconsistencia en el uso de mayúsculas/minúsculas.